# Sorting in Pivot Table on how data is summarized, not just the value

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, pivot-table

Often I am creating pivot tables that summarize some count by some category.  Let's say I am counting Yes/No responses by some category.  I usually add the count field and display it as a "% of row", and then create a pivot chart.  However, if I want to sort one of the columns, say "Yes", Excel sorts by the underlying count, not the calculated percentage.  Any way around this?

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Where can I host pics to post?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26365/is-there-a-way-to-attach-images-to-a-question

Comment: @mindless.panda Did you ever figure out how to post pictures? :P